# Release version works unexpectedly - memory races and strange QThread behaviour

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, memory-leaks

I wrote whole application in debug mode and everything works fine in this mode. Unfortunately, now when I trying to run release app two unexpected things happen.
Base information:
Qt 5.1.1
Qt Creator 2.8.1
Windows 7 64x
Application has got second thread which decapsulated data from buffer which is update in main thread.

First problem - memory race:
In one of my methods strange memory race occures in release version - in debug everything is ok. Method looks like:

```
std::vector<double> dataVec;
std::vecotr<unsigned char> frame("U+014-00300027950l");
//EFrame_AccXPos == 1;
dataVec.push_back(decapsulateAcc(frame.begin()+EFrame_AccXPos));

        double Deserializator::decapsulateAcc(std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator pos)
        {
            const char frac[2] = {*(pos+2),*(pos+3)};
            const char integ[] = {*(pos+1)};
            double sign;

            if (*pos == consts::frame::plusSign) {
                sign = 1.0;
            } else {
                sign = -1.0;
            }
            double integer = (std::strtod(integ, 0));
            double fractial = (std::strtod(frac, 0))/100;

            qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(std::string(integ));
                //prints "014Rd??j?i" should be "0 ?s"
            qDebug() << QString::number(integer);
                //prints "14" should be "0"
            qDebug() << QString::number(fractial);
                //prints "0.14" - everything ok.

            return sign*integer+sign*fractial;
        }
```

What wrong with this method?

Second problem:
In additional thread I emit signal to manage data which it decapsulate from buffer. After emit thread wait until flag change to false. When I add some qDebug prints - it's start works, but without them it blocks (even though the flag is already false). Below code:

```
    void DataManager::sendPlottingRequest()
    {
        numberOfMessurement++;
        if (numberOfMessurement == plotAfterEquals ) {
            numberOfMessurement = consts::startsFromZero;
            isStillPlotting=true;
            emit requestPlotting(dataForChart);
                //block in next line
            while (isStillPlotting);
            //it starts work when:
            //int i = 0;
            //while (isStillPlotting) {
            //i++
            //if (i == 10000) qDebug() << isStillPlotting;
            //}
        }
    }

void DataManager::continueProcess()
{
    plottingState++;
    if (plottingState == consts::plottingFinished) {
            //program reach this point
        isStillPlotting = false;
        plottingState = consts::startsFromZero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok - first is sloved: in initialization of table is should be \0 at the end, eg: const char integ[2] = {*(pos+1), '\0'};.

Answer (score 1):

`while (isStillPlotting);` gets optimized out to `if(isStillPlotting)while(true);`

you should make `isStillPlotting` volatile or use an atomicInt instead.

or you can emit a signal `plottingDone()` from the `if` in `continueProcess()` and then connect the slot that executes the code that is after the while